# python beautiful-soap json - scrape one page but not the other similar ones

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape a nutritional website and the following code works

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

page = requests.get("https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3071/1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all("script")
for script in scripts:
    if 'foodNutrients = ' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('foodNutrients =')[-1]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit('fillSpanValues')[0]
        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit(';',1)[0]
        jsonStr = "".join(jsonStr.split())

        valid_json = re.sub(r'([{,:])(\w+)([},:])', r'\1"\2"\3', jsonStr)
        jsonObj = json.loads(valid_json)

# These are in terms of 100 grams. I also calculated for per serving       
g_per_serv = int(jsonObj['FOODSERVING_WEIGHT_1'].split('(')[-1].split('g')[0])

for k, v in jsonObj.items():
    if k == 'NUTRIENT_0':
        conv_v = (float(v)*g_per_serv)/100

        print ('%s : %s (per 100 grams)   |   %s (per serving %s' %(k, round(float(v)), round(float(conv_v)), jsonObj['FOODSERVING_WEIGHT_1']  ))
```

but when I try and use it on other almost identical webpages on the same domain it does not. For example if I use

```
page = requests.get("https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/vegetables-and-vegetable-products/2383/2")
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape_test_2.py", line 20, in <module>
    jsonObj = json.loads(valid_json)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 5446 (char 5445)
```

looking at the source code for both pages they seem identical in the sense they both have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    foodNutrients = { NUTRIENT_142: ........
```

which is the part being scraped.

Ive been looking at this all day, does anyone know how to make this script work for both pages, what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would switch to using hjson which allows unquoted keys and simply extract the entire `foodNutrient`s variable and parse rather than manipulating strings over and over.

---

**Your error:**

Currently yours is failing due the number of elements in at least one of the source arrays being a different length and thus your regex to sanitize is inappropriate. We examine only the first known occurrence...

In first url, before you use regex to clean you have:

```
aifr:"[ -35, -10 ]"
```

after:

```
"aifr":"[-35,-10]"
```

In second you start with a different length array:

```
aifr:"[ 163, 46, 209, 179, 199, 117, 11, 99, 7, 5, 82 ]"
```

after regex replace, instead of:

```
"aifr":"[ 163, 46, 209, 179, 199, 117, 11, 99, 7, 5, 82 ]"
```

you have:

```
"aifr":"[163,"46",209,"179",199,"117",11,"99",7,"5",82]"
```

i.e. invalid json. No more nicely delimited key:value pairs.

---

**Nutshell:**

Use hjson it's easier. Or update regex appropriately to handle variable length arrays.

```
import requests, re, hjson

urls = ['https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/nut-and-seed-products/3071/1','https://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/vegetables-and-vegetable-products/2383/2']

p = re.compile(r'foodNutrients = (.*?);')

with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        r = s.get(url)
        jsonObj = hjson.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
        serving_weight = jsonObj['FOODSERVING_WEIGHT_1']
        g_per_serv = int(serving_weight.split('(')[-1].split('g')[0])
        nutrient_0 = jsonObj['NUTRIENT_0']
        conv_v = float(nutrient_0)*g_per_serv/100
        print('%s : %s (per 100 grams)   |   %s (per serving %s' %(nutrient_0, round(float(nutrient_0)), round(float(conv_v)), serving_weight))
```

Comment: Add in the space after print key word if using Python 2

Comment: woah! this is great. I had no idea about `hjson`. Wonderful solution QHarr. I'm starring this so that I can remember to look back at this in the future.

Comment: @chitown88 Thank one of the long time users which is where I first saw hjson used. I think by Martijn Pieters♦. It is cool isn't it!